# how can i align two objects and see them from each side with 1,3,7?

Tags: modeling

If i have a cube and a beziercircle, both rotated randomly.

How can I make the beziercircle exactly around the cube on his orientation?

[image]

wanted result:

[image]

And is there a way to see these 2 objects now from all sides as if they were flat on xy? as i can see things when pressing 1,3,7 ?

so i would like them to see them like this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select your cube and in the *Transform Orientations* panel, click on the "+" to create a custom orientation:

[image]

Select the circle and *Object > Transform > Align to Transform Orientation*:

[image]

Also with some <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> put the 3D cursor at the cube location, select the circle and put it at the same location:

[image]

To see their front, side and top view press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>:

[image]